# CodeIgniter - Error Number: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'personaje'

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is the database error that i'm getting:

```
Error Number: 1066

Not unique table/alias: 'personaje'

SELECT `personaje_nombre` FROM `personaje`, `personaje`
```

And my model is this:

```
function obtenerheroes(){
        $sql = "SELECT personaje_nombre FROM personaje"
        $heroe = $this->db->query($sql);
        $resultado = $heroe->row_array();
        if($resultado!=null){
            return $resultado
        }
        else{
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

My table is this one:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`personaje` (
  `idpersonaje` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `personaje_nombre` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `personaje_nombrereal` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `personaje_historia` MEDIUMTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `editorial_ideditorial` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idpersonaje`, `editorial_ideditorial`),
  INDEX `fk_personaje_editorial_idx` (`editorial_ideditorial` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_personaje_editorial`
    FOREIGN KEY (`editorial_ideditorial`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`editorial` (`ideditorial`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

Please help I can't find my mistake in my code , i can't make it work :(

Comment: Shouldn't say that if your query is truly `SELECT personaje_nombre FROM personaje`... Are you sure the error it comes from `obtenerheroes()` ? This error happens when you execute a query from a table twice, without specifying an alias for each one - eg `SELECT per.personaje_nombre FROM personaje per INNER JOIN personaje per2 ON ...`

Comment: also you have missed a **;** at the end of this line `$sql = "SELECT personaje_nombre FROM personaje"`

Comment: @EhsanT The semicolon is a query *separator*, and as such is never necessary unless you're using `mysqli_multi_query()`.

Comment: @Narf I didn't mean the ; for query, but the ; for the  **PHP Instruction separator**

Comment: @EhsanT Oh, my bad then.

Comment: @Narf :) no problem